# Difference between strategy.exit and strategy.close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm struggling with some oddities using exit() and close().  My understanding is that the main difference is that exit is for limit orders and close is for market orders.  So if I have the following (assume long), they should produce the same results except one as a limit order and one as market order.

```
if (close > someTargetPrice)
   strategy.close('order id', comment = 'closing', immediately = true

strategy.exit('order id', limit = someTargetPrice, comment='closing')
```

I'm not seeing this behavior.  The "limit" logic for strategy.exit must be somehow different?  Also strategy.close() ALWAYS closes on the bar close, not on any other tick.  I have set my strategy to run on every update (hloc).

Why do I care?  When I pyramid, and I hit a stop or take profit, I want to exit that in a single order exactly when the condition is hit.  strategy.exit will issue one order per.  strategy close will issue a single for all.  But, it always closes on the bar, not on the tick.  Can anyone shed some let on this weird behavior

Comment: Are you talking about real time bars or historical bars?

Comment: I've seen the same behavior on both

Comment: problem #1: You want to exit by limit but with pyramiding is on multiple exists are issued, but you need exit by single order.

Comment: problem #2: When you exit position by `strategy.close` your all entries are closed by single order, but with market order (by last price - close).

Comment: It's like that?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The difference is enough on strategy close to significantly change backtesting results.  I have tried immediately=true, and doesn't help.